# node async library filterLimit always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-async

I'm trying to async filter a list of file paths to return only existing files. I'm using the `async` library's [filterLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#filterLimit) along with `fs-extra`. Function below:

```js
const asyncFilter = require('async').filterLimit;
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');

async function filterFiles(fileList){
  const existing = await asyncFilter(fileList, 5, (file, callback) => {
    console.log(file); // looks good

    fsExtra.pathExists(file, (err, exists) => {
       const result = err ? false : exists;
       console.log(result); // looks good (boolean)

       callback(null, result);
    });
  });

  console.log(existing); // always undefined...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2: Both suggestions below do not work... here is a **working version** where the deprecated `fs.exists()` was replaced with `fs.access()`

```js
const async = require('async');
const fs = require('fs');

async function filterFiles(fileList) {
    try {

        const result = await async.filterLimit(fileList, 5, function(filePath, callback) {
            fs.access(filePath, function(err) {
                callback(null, !err)
            });
        });

        console.log(result);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

---

Can't you simply do:

**NOT WORKING**

```js
    const asyncFilter = require('async').filterLimit;
    const fs = require('fs');

    async function filterFiles(fileList) {
        let result = [];
        await asyncFilter(fileList, 5, fs.exists, function(existing) {
            // array of existing files
            console.log(existing);
            // now assign the existing files to result array
            result = existing;
        });
        // should be the same as existing in callback function
        console.log(result);
    };
```

no need for `fs-extra`. I think your issue is that `async.filterLimit()` does not return anything but executes a callback function, so just by assigning `async.filterLimit()` to a variable does not mean you get the result in there, you'll get `undefined` because the function does not return anything!

EDIT: Adapted snippet from above based on @Jaromanda X's comment:

```js
    const asyncFilter = require('async').filterLimit;
    const fs = require('fs');

    async function filterFiles(fileList) {
        let result = await asyncFilter(fileList, 5, fs.exists);
        // should contain only existing files
        console.log(result);
    };
```

Comment: However, since filterLimit is asynchronous, you'll be executing `console.log(result)` before any `fs.exists` as run ... what you need to do with your code is remove the callback from `asyncFilter` so that it does return a Promise

Comment: looks like it should work based on documentation - isn't it amazing how 8  lines of code in the question reduced to a single line when you use libraries properly :p

Comment: Thank you for the tip on simplifying my code. I like your adapted snippet. However, I still get back `undefined` from the `await asyncFilter()` call.

Comment: Also, async.filterLimit does return a Promise. It should be compatible with await syntax.

Comment: @bazaars check the latest edit (2), this time I tested it locally and it seems to work...